# Django 3 - doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django 3 but having a problem. My app is called calc1. Code below:

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Dreamreal(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    db_table = "dreamreal"
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
import time
from .models import Dreamreal
from django.http import HttpResponse



# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    return render(request, 'home.html',{'today' :today}) 


def crudops(request):        
    dreamreal = Dreamreal(
      website = "www.vlcbt.org.uk", mail = "info@vlcbt.org.uk",
      name = "John", phonenumber = "08767655665"
    )

    dreamreal.save()

    # read all entries and print
    objects = Dreamreal.objects.all()
    res ="printing all documents <br>"
    for elt in objects: 
        res += elt.name +"<br>"

    return HttpResponse(res)
```

When I try to migrate I get the following error message:

File "C:\Users\john\Envs\lms\Scripts\projects\jkjlms\calc1\urls.py", line 3, in 
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\john\Envs\lms\Scripts\projects\jkjlms\calc1\views.py", line 5, in 
    from .models import Dreamreal
  File "C:\Users\john\Envs\lms\Scripts\projects\jkjlms\calc1\models.py", line 5, in 
    class Dreamreal(models.Model):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 115, in **new**
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class calc1.models.Dreamreal doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should add your app in settings.py file in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...,
    calc1,
]
```

Also, before migration you should do `python manage.py makemigrations calc1`

Answer (score 0):

Just add Django's Sites framework to your apps and set `SITE_ID` to 1 in your settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```